# POST object to API, but API can't read it

Tags: node.js, post, express, oauth-2.0, instagram-api

I'm using Axios to send a POST request to the Instagram API:

```
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
axios.post('https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token', {
    client_id: 'zzz',
    client_secret: 'zzz',
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8080/oauth2',
    code: 'zzz',
  }).then(function(res) {
    console.log("response ", res);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log("err ", err);
  });
```

This follows the example given in the Instagram API docs (https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/):

```
  // curl -F 'client_id=CLIENT_ID' \
  //   -F 'client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET' \
  //   -F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
  //   -F 'redirect_uri=AUTHORIZATION_REDIRECT_URI' \
  //   -F 'code=CODE' \
  //   https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
```

However, the following error is returned:

```
data: {
  code: 400,
  error_type: 'OAuthException',
  error_message: 'You must provide a client_id'
}
```

When I use Chrome Postman, I don't have any issue; I receive an authorization token. So apparently the API isn't reading what I am sending, but I can't figure out why. I've set my headers:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, content-type, accept, authorization');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
});
```

Also I even made the same POST to http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ and as expected, I receive the correct response.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

EDIT:

I just noticed that when I use Chrome Postman, it only works with the x-www-form-urlencoded setting. I have tried submitting it with JSON and a number of other ways but I receive the same error as noted below.

Comment: use **application/json** instead of **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**?

Comment: Tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: application/x-www-form-urlencoded is used to send form data. Just by a brief look at instagram API you want to send query string - Add parameters to actual url ie. https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=zzz&client_secret=zzz...

Comment: Hmm. This doesn't work. Also, in their example, they use POST -f (it's included in the question), so I wonder if I have to use form data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to make an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request via axios from a node.js application:

```
var querystring = require('querystring');

axios.post('http://something.com/foo', querystring.stringify({
  'bar': 123
});
```

Please note that you don't need to set the `Content-Type` header. It will be set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` automatically.